# Cursor with typed javascript library skips to new line and doesnt 'type' out works

Tags: javascript, jquery, typed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style >

.typed-cursor{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

</style>


<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="typed.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = element>
<script>
  $(function(){
      $(".element").typed({
        strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
        typeSpeed: 0,
        loop: true,
        cursorChar: "$",
      });
  });
</script>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

When I run the page, the cursor skips to the next line and the words come up infinitly. I would like the cursor to stick with the words, going back and forth. A demo on the creators home page shows how I would like the cursor to be (http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/). I'm not sure what I'm missing, I'm guessing its small though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the element class.  Try this instead:

change

```
<div class = element>
```

to

```
<div class = "element">
```

---

**EDIT**

Actually, you should be using a `<span>` element, not a `<div>`.

Comment: Seems to work for me. I created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dc2uwvoy/  See what you're doing differently.

Comment: I looked at that, looks exactly like what my output is, the '$' isn't moving with the text, it is on the next line.

Comment: Ah. I see now. I misunderstood how typed was supposed to work. Updated the fiddle. Seems that you need to replace div with span. Maybe you should raise a github issue with the project?

Answer (score 1):

```
display: inline;
```

Tried setting the display to both inline and inline-block as suggested on lots of sites.. but this solves my issue... use above code in CSS....

you can check demo:

> http://www.problogbooster.com/